# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] Android-L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to use the new CardView from Android L. I updated everything in the SDK manager, but I keep getting the following error:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "www.thomascbeerten.com.nieuwetests"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.1.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Recently there was a post here regarding the L SDK's incompatibility
>   with prior versions of Android. I've been digging in AOSP repositories
>   for quite a few hours now, and determined that the tools behave this
>   way because they are designed to treat preview platforms differently.
>   If you compile against a preview SDK (android-L), the build tools will
>   lock minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to that same API level. This
>   results in the produced application being unable to be installed on
>   devices running older releases of Android, even if your application
>   isn't doing anything specific to L. To make matters worse, the new
>   support libs (CardView, RecyclerView, Palette, etc.) are also locked
>   into the L API level, even though--according to their repository
>   names--they should work on API level 7 just fine (and they do!).

See my Reddit post about this [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/), with a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the great article! Now I fully understand :)

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/237685) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: so you should follow the guide at  http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/ and you'll be able to install on older devices at the same time as compiling with android L

Answer (score 5):

Once you have the above issues resolved as mentioned by Eddie. You might also run into another error;;

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
```

This will be present in your styles.xml . The quick fix is to replace it with the following below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
<!--<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
```

to

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion '21.0.2'
```

Note `android-L` is in single quotes but `21` isn't. `21` is an integer and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile with L it actually makes a change during compilation setting your minsdkversion to L. If you want to use RecyclerView or CardView I would recommend checking out [RecyclerViewLib](https://github.com/twotoasters/RecyclerViewLib). RecyclerView and CardView have been moving into this library so that there is no min version L problem. The author also explained in his [blog post](http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/03/unlocking-recyclerview/) how all L related code was removed to make it safe to use.

To add RecyclerViewLb to your project just add the following line to your dependencies in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.twotoasters.RecyclerViewLib:library:1.0.+@aar'
```

You then do not want to add the `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'` to your build.gradle as you will get that through RecyclerViewLib.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. This can happen when your min sdk version and built targets are set to a higher API level/OS version than your phone is running. If you're using Android Studio, go to File > Project Structure > and edit relavent settings then Run again.