# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK with minSdkVersion lower than device API version

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

On a brand new install of the latest AndroidStudio running the New Project template with min SDK selection of 15 (ICS) trying to run on a Nexus 5 running API 19, I get the INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK error with the following output.  I have made no changes to the project from what the template has generated, so this would be a clean first run that I would expect to work.

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_5-{device id}
Uploading file
    local path: /home/{my user name}/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.{my user name}.myapplication
Installing com.example.{my user name}.myapplication
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.{my user name}.myapplication"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.{my user name}.myapplication
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

This is the default build.gradle file generated for the app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.{my user name}.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: are you sure about `targetSdkVersion 'L'`? shouldn't it be `targetSdkVersion 21`?

Comment: @njzk2 That's what AndroidStudio generated.  I did notice that and try changing it to 20, and that didn't work either

Comment: did you also modify the compile version that has "android-L"?

Comment: I believe this was discussed over here earlier today ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457831/failure-install-failed-older-sdk-android-l

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465289/android-studio-failure-install-failed-older-sdk/24601830#24601830

Answer (score 4):

Check the doc at http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html.

You have to use

```
minSdkVersion 'L'
```

and you have to run the app in device with Android-L or an emulator with Android-L.
The build system when `compileSdkVersion` is `'android-L'` or `targetSdkVersion` is `'L'` forces the minSdk to `'L'` to prevent apps published with the API in preview.