# Android Studio : Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Today I have downloaded Android Studio v 0.8.0 beta. I am trying to test my app on SDK 17 . Android studio error `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`
Here is my android manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vahe_muradyan.notes" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It seems that android studio uses configurations in build.gradle.Here is build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vahe_muradyan.notes"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Comment: Add this code to your AndroidManifest.xml                              <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"/> before <application tag.

Comment: the same error . pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.vahe_muradyan.notes
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Comment: which device have you test ?

Comment: SDK version 17 , Android 4.2.1

Comment: Eclipse tested apps on my Device well. Today I have downloaded Android Studio and I am having that error now .

Comment: I think try to install latest sdk from sdk manager.

Comment: Which one do you use ? Eclipse or Android Studio

Comment: Android Studio last 1 year.

Comment: Do you test on a real device?

Comment: You can't do it.
Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459359/install-failed-older-sdk-with-minsdkversion-lower-than-device-api-version/24460201#24460201

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failure \[INSTALL\_FAILED\_OLDER\_SDK\] Android-L](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457831/failure-install-failed-older-sdk-android-l)

Comment: I just changed targetSdkVersion in defaultConfig to 20 and it worked for me

Answer (score 27):

There are my config to support L and old versions of android:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.uladzimir_klyshevich.myapplication"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    productFlavors {
        l {
            minSdkVersion 'android-L'
            targetSdkVersion 'android-L'
            compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
        }
        old {
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 20
            //TODO comment second line if build is not compiles for "L"
            compileSdkVersion 20
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    lCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    oldCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

As result you will have flavors:

```
oldDebug
oldRelease
lDebug
lRelease
```

And can install your application on old versions of android.

Comment: Hmm...for me, this new info just confuses ME even more. I haven't yet even digested what 'Android-L' is.  And maybe EVENTUALLY I might want to have various 'product flavors', but right now, I just want to get one or any set of values to load into my Nexus-7, running v4.4.4. My thought was that Google is now discouraging continuing to use the older '<uses-sdk>' info in the Manifest, because when I put it there, when using Android-Studio 0.8.1, it flashes on the screen that it intends to IGNORE that info, because presumably, it's getting somewhere else now.

Comment: Is this meant for mobile/build.gradle or wear/build.gradle? Neither seems to work as the IDE complains "cannot resolve symbol 'compileSdkVersion'"

Comment: This is for mobile/build.gradle. Wear is the another project and you can compile his with any other sdk.

Comment: Its giving an error cannot resolve symbol 'compileSdkVersion' in product flavors.

Comment: what is file name to write this ?

Comment: How did you solve conflicts with `android:Theme.Material.Light` theme when building the old flavor?

Comment: Are you sure it is possible to compile with a different version per flavor?

Comment: I could not do it. During build with flavor gradle takes compile sdk from the first flavor.

Comment: Is this going to be necessary with the production version of L or is it just a workaround for the preview?

Answer (score 12):

Do those changes in `build.gradle` file in the wear module

```
compileSdkVersion 20
targetSdkVersion 20
```

So the final **wear/build.gradle** content will be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your package name"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had similar issues. Seems that changing the 'L' to 20 in this mysterious build.gradle file solves the issue. Never thought I'd say this, but I find myself missing Eclipse...

Comment: What is the difference between sdk 20 and 'android-L'?

Comment: You can find in the Build.VERSION_CODES following: public static final int KITKAT = 19;
        public static final int KITKAT_WATCH = 20;
        public static final int L = 10000;

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Android Studio Beta version 0.8.1 and I have the same problem. I now I sold my problem by changing the AVD (I'm using Genymotion) to API 19.
and here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.daroath.actionbar"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

[image]

Hope this help!

Comment: when you say changing the avd, do you mean the version in the android manifest file? you edited it in a text editor? what was it before?

Comment: no, in android studio the way you change "android sdk" is no more in manifest file, but u change it in "gradle.build" file instead.As my experience of the error is that when I set my gradle.build file like defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.daroath.actionbar"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    } I need to choose an AVD with API19 or higher to run it.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by downloading api level 20 using sdk manager and changing every string that points to **android-L**. I did it because I dont have a kitkat device and don't want to use emulator.
[image]
See the image download the marked one.

Here's my build config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20//changed this from default
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.subash.test"
    minSdkVersion 12//changed this from default
    targetSdkVersion 20//changed this from default
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Do you can use Material theme with these config?

Comment: for that you will need either emulator or device with material theme

Comment: Aha! Now I see (said the blind man)!  So, now no matter what value I put into that new layout, for 'targetSdkVersion', Android Studio pops up an error, asking me to first INSTALL that version of the SDK, and to then re-sync the project.  SO: The problem is that, even tho my SDK-manager says that all these various SDKs are installed (they always were), that suddenly this new Android-Studio must be looking in a diff place, to be able to find them.  (I don't know the fix yet.  Removing all my SDKs from 10 to 20 is NOT recommended, so I'll sit quietly til someone else discovers the needed-tweak.)

Comment: @Dave could you explain your problem exactly? the targetsdkversion and the compilesdk version both need to change(no need to specify app version in manifest in AS) according to what you have. I didnot have a android 4.4L device so I changed it. The above works for me so it should work for you too

Comment: Sorry...so today, I followed your recipe, and got rid of my 'Android-L'  crap, and went back to putting numbered sdk-values in. Which is causing a different problem, in that now the builds no longer work...it says it can't find any of my earlier-installed numerical sdks.  So, I'm thinking it can ONLY find that newly added Android-L sdk, so when I ask for anything older, I get this other problem.  (Sigh.)

Comment: Ok, (re)started fresh, by completely removing Android-Studio install, then installed full 0.8.0 kit, and let it upgrade to 0.8.1.  On both an existing (previous proj from 0.6.x) and on a new proj in 0.8.1, I use the generated build.gradle file as is, and get INDICATIONS of a clean build on each project.  But, the kicker is: when I 'cd' to top of either proj-directory-tree, and search for '*.apk', I find no generated APK file! Conclusion: Google's 0.8.x kits for Android Studio are NOT YET READY FOR PRIME-TIME. This is on Win-7 64-bit, using search cmd 'dir /s *.apk'

Comment: Hmmm...see the bullet "Automatic platform component downloading during Gradle sync when a required platform is missing", at the webpage [ http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudiobetareleased ]. I WAS seeing that prompt, when I alter the config to quit using 'android-L' and 'L', and tell it to use a numbered sdk, such as 19 or 18, etc.  NOW I'm thinking that starting in 0.8.0, they are needing to COPY the specified SDK from its installed area (external to Android-Studio) into Android-Studio's installed-directory-tree.  If so, there seems to be a glitch/bug...that dialog won't work for me.

Comment: At any rate, I'm declaring my canary (i.e. 0.8.1) DEAD! Translation: If  we want to get any real dev-work done, we need to drop back to 0.6.x of Android-Studio, or use Eclipse, etc.  Enough said?  As always, tho, YMMV

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before switching to build 19 is the suggested route here until v20 is "fixed". This thread helped me solve the issue, but it seems similar answers have been posted here as well. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72840

Comment: 2nd this. I removed v20 and L of build tools and android image and replaced with 19.1 build tools and Level 19. Then I removed the project and recreated it and now I can run my programs.

Answer (score 2):

Change file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` worked for me on Android Studio(Beta)0.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

basically means that the installation has failed due to the target location (AVD/Device) having an older SDK version than the `targetSdkVersion` specified in your app.

**FROM**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 'L' //Avoid String change to 20 without quotes
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vahe_muradyan.notes"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 'L' //Set your correct Target which is 17 for Android 4.2.2
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+' // Avoid Generalization 
// can lead to dependencies issues remove +

}
```

**TO**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20 
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vahe_muradyan.notes"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}
```

This is common error from eclipse to now Android Studio 0.8-.8.6

**Things to avoid in Android Studio (As for now)**

- Avoid Strings instead set API level/Number
- Avoid generalizing dependencies + be specific

Answer (score 2):

in the AndroidManifest.xml file change the user-sdk to older version
 `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>`

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research i found the solution for this huge error which i was struggling for 2 days.

Instead of changing the minSdkVerison & targetSdkVersion in build.gradle

Just open the Manifest file and use this

```
<uses-sdk 
android:minSdkVersion="17" 
android:targetSdkVersion="21"/
```

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is that with vanilla Android Studio v 0.8 beta, it only installs/recognize SDK 20 which is android L. In order to target another complieSDK you need to install it via the SDK manager. Once it is set, you can then change the compileSDK to a lower version and it should work.

you may also want to restrict the compatibility library, it needs to be restricted from using the latest version of the library so change the dependecy to something like :

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0') {
    // really use 19.1.0 even if something else resolves higher
    force = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem.
I just modified the compileSdk Version from android_L to 19
to target my nexus 4.4.4.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    **compileSdkVersion 'android-L'** modified to 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.antwei.uiframework.ui"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    **compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'** modified to compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

how to modified the value by ide.

select file->Project Structure -> Facets -> android-gradle and then modified the compile Sdk Version from android_L to 19

sorry I don't have enough reputation to add pictures

Answer (score 1):

I initially went into the SDK Manager and updated all that it had set to update.

I also added in the SDK version for the version of Android I had on the Droid I had...Version 2.3.4(10)

I don't think that really fixed anything, and after a Android Studio restart as recommended after the SDK installs, I changed the minSdkVersion to 8 in the build.gradle file

I was then able to download the application to my Droid.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cmcjr.chuck.droid_u"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

This is Android Studio installed on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Just go to `build.gradle(Module:App)` and change the `minSdkVersion` to whatever you are using with emulator.

Example:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.raghu.sample"
        // Change the version in following line
        minSdkVersion 10 // <-- Whatever you are using with Emulator
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Android Studio v 0.8.1 beta and ran into the same problem targeting SDK 19.

Copied 19 from the adt-bundle to android-studio, changed build.gradle to:

compileSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 19

then project -> app -> open module settings (aka project structure): change compile sdk version to 19.

Now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a few posts prior - I went to SDK Manager and uninstalled v20 and version L.  Then I installed version 19 and this problem was resolved and I could debug using my android device, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to support Android L is to use custom `lpreview` property for Gradle. For instance:

```
lpreview = hasProperty('lpreview')

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion lpreview ? "android-L" : 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    productFlavors { lpreview ? lpreview{} : classic{} }

    defaultConfig lpreview ? {} : {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
```

Now, you can build your app with:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew -Plpreview assembleDebug
```

or

```
./gradlew -Plpreview installLpreviewDebug
```

This way you can build your app with `lpreview` property for Android L and without it for previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you sdk min version

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the  'minSdkVersion' in your build.gradle

The default project creates it with the latest API, so if you're phone is not yet up-dated (e.g. **minSdkVersion 21**), which is probably your case.

Make sure the **minSdkVersion** value matches with the device API version or if the device has a  higher one.

Example:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'xxxxxx'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your device older than `minSDK` , edit `minSdkVersion` in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

One more place where minSdkVersion makes a sense is a flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        minSdkVersion 22
    }
    prod {
        minSdkVersion 9
    }
}
```

minSdkVersion (22) will not install on development devices with API level older than 22.

Answer (score 0):

you need update.

This is my current solution (09/2015).

In Android Studio search.

```
Menu --> Help --> check for update
```

Upate and problem solved!!

**Good luck**

Answer (score 0):

Check the minimum API level inside the build.gradle(module: app)[inside of the gradle scripts].
Thatt should be equal to or lower than the device you use

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle change minSdkVersion 17 or later.