# Using colorPrimaryDark in older sdk like Kitkat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

im trying to use this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24633486/4707917

**but it didnt work for kitkat...**

and i need only ***colorPrimaryDark*** like Lollipop in kitkat or older sdk.(Without any Library !)

ide:android studio.

any Solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information provided below is based on this [blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) by someone that works for the Android team.

You can do this by using the android support libraries. First add a dependency on the v7 support library to your **build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

You can now use the `colorPrimaryDark` property in your **themes.xml** file. All you need to do is make sure that your style inherits from an appcompat style, for example: `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

> Please note that this will only affect the styles of the action bar.