# Error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 0.82
and I have encountered the error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK].

I have wrote the following lines in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
*<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />*
```

and this is my build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "Comss.sskapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

After trying to fix with your answers : 
My new build.gradle looks like this now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId"ComImOK.imokapp"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml  :

```
*<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />*
```

In addition my style is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">-->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

and still the same error

Comment: Dear friend did you check that android:minSdkVersion="8" and minSdkVersion 15 they point to diferent sdk versions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 19
```

(or 17 or 20 as you like)

Even with minSdk with less than `L`, with `compileSdkVersion` to L the error will appear.

The same for

```
targetSdkVersion 'L'
```

Answer (score 0):

As @HocineHamdi  mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465289/android-studio-failure-install-failed-older-sdk) you would need to make some changes in  `build.gradle` file in the wear module.
The edit would  be

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your package name"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

Comment: why you include a dependency for wear devices? who said he need it? in his build it's not there