# Android Studio 0.8.6: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Debugging my app with Android Studio 0.8.6, I get the error: "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bla.towerofhanoi"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':third_party:andengine')
}
```

Comment: You can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465289/android-studio-failure-install-failed-older-sdk
This question is a possible duplicate

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting another error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624256/android-studio-0-8-6-error-installing-android-sdk-platform-20

Comment: This is the same link you posted above ...

Comment: I am getting the error "failed to find target android-20 : C:\android-studio\sdk" Install missing platform(s) and sync project

Answer (score 0):

Add `<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />` in your manifest file and sync project.

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc at http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html.

You have to use

```
  minSdkVersion 'L'
```

and you have to run the app in device with Android-L or an emulator with Android-L.
The build system when `compileSdkVersion` is `'android-L'` or `targetSdkVersion` is `'L'` forces the minSdk to `'L'` to prevent apps published with the API in preview.

Comment: I have an Android device with Android 4.4.4. How can I debug my app with this?