# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] with android wear project

Tags: android, wear-os

I am using android studio and I downloaded everything upto Android 5.0 in sdk manager. With a classic projet I run my app on moto G with no problems, but when I create a Wear project I face this error :
`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]?`

There is part of my build.gradle :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'stream.lib.myapplication'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio : Failure \[INSTALL\_FAILED\_OLDER\_SDK\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465289/android-studio-failure-install-failed-older-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: by default the wear project get selected in `Select/run Debug configuration` I changed to mobile project.