# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]|

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, genymotion

**I do not find an answer. help!**

*I can not emulate my app that I get the error title .. all my information from the device and project is as follows:*

Choose Device:

samsung GT-19300 Android 4.3(API 18) ---> No, minSdk(API 20) > deviceSdk(API 18)

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.bluezone.win"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

> `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="20"  android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>`

What should I do?

Comment: minSdkVersion 17 to 20 in your gradle code

Comment: @NovusMobile  Thanks for your help ..
I just did and displays the same error.

Comment: buddy change same for the AndroidManifest also.

Comment: @NovusMobile minSdkVersion change my AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle 17 to 20 and continues to give the same error. I am that I cry .

Comment: add logs what it will say.

Comment: normally the version in your manifest isn't used anymore, you should be able to remove that.

Comment: @SnyersK   Sorry and I edit my question and I did everything they told me ! I appreciate your help again !

Comment: have you try on other device ? maybe it bug from your device

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat I try and follow the same error. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the minSdkVerison & targetSdkVersion in build.gradle

Just open the Manifest file and use this

```
<uses-sdk 
android:minSdkVersion="17" 
android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Ref : [Android Studio : Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465289/android-studio-failure-install-failed-older-sdk)

Comment: I did everything as you said but still gives the same error:  Failure [ INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK ]...thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below code

```
   android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.bluezone.win"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

also remove sdk stuff from manifest file

```
<uses-sdk 
android:minSdkVersion="17" 
android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Comment: follows the same error: Failure [ INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK ]...thanks for your help!

Comment: I am prepared for teamviewer a remote assistance if you want you can add me to skype: juankmilo0493