# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] when installing Android Wear sample app

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I followed the instructions at [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) to create a simple mobile/wearable app in Android Studio. However, upon trying to run it I am getting the error "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]". My problem seems to be like the one [asked at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540809/trouble-setting-up-hello-world-watch-app-in-android-studio), however unlike that user the reddit post that is linked to didn't contain any information that helped me (it basically suggested to add < uses-sdk tools:node="replace" /> to the android manifest, but android studio didn't like the tools thing." My build.gradle files are exactly the same as those at the above link. I just updated Android Studio today (0.8.2) and have installed all necessary SDK's. Many people are getting this error but mine is unique in that I'm targeting the Wear stuff and not concerned with Android L. Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `minSdkVersion 20` and `targetSdkVersion 20` in the wear module?

Comment: Yes. The gradle files are the same as in the post I linked.

Comment: And for the mobile module?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540809/trouble-setting-up-hello-world-watch-app-in-android-studio). Basically instead of deploying to the phone like the instructions say to, you have to enable bluetooth debugging and deploy directly to the watch.

Answer (score 0):

Do those changes in build.gradle file in the wear module

compileSdkVersion 20
targetSdkVersion 20

So the final wear/build.gradle content will be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your package name"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```