# Card_view material design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I am trying to use `card_view`. But it keeps giving an error.

> Error:(13) No resource identifier found for attribute `'cardCornerRadius' in package 'com.google.example.test_app'

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#610B0B"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:id="@+id/myactivity ">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#fff"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="5dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it appears that cardCornerRadius does not exist :)

Comment: @DanielBo this is what the developer.android site told me to add. Is there anyway i can make it work like this?

Comment: does it run if your dont call it?

Comment: I got it working now with the dependencies. :)

Comment: Care to tell how you added the dependencies? I added     
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
And it did not work :/

Comment: @jelleroggle now me also facing same bug.  how u solve this problem?

Comment: @jonas if you've added the dependency, try adding xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to the layout.

Answer (score 21):

EDIT: This has been fixed in the Android 5.0 Lollipop SDK. Simply add

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
```

to your build.gradle and you're good to go.

OLD answer:

You'll need to add the cardview support library dependency to build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
```

However, due to the way Google built the library, you'll also have to compile your app using the latest "L" SDK:

```
compileSdkVersion "android-L"
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
```

and

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion "L"
```

Note that the minSdkVersion here doesn't really matter - as long as you compile with "L" SDK, your app can only run on L device/emulator no matter what minSdkVersion is specified.

The only viable way to build with the cardview lib for earlier Android version seems to be using Eddie Ringle's [workaround](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/).

See [Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] Android-L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457831/failure-install-failed-older-sdk-android-l) for some related info.

Comment: Hi mindex, are you saying that basically for the time being we cannot use the CardView for "real" implementations? Thanks

Comment: @LisaAnne you may want to check out http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/03/unlocking-recyclerview/

Comment: It fixed the issue completely!
But try to avoiding Cardview/Recyclerview jars if you are on Studio. In eclipse you still need jars. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

For eclipse We need to include both the things add `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` as a library project and also add + check it's jar file in java build path

- Go to File -> Import -> Existing Android code into workspace -->
  Browse (Go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview) --> Click ok
  --> Click Finish
- Right click on cardview project --> Properties --> Android(Left Pane)
  --> Enable isLibrary (tick the checkbox) --> Apply --> ok
- Right click on your project --> Properties --> Android(Left pane) -->
  Add (under library) --> cardview --> apply --> ok
- Right click on your project again --> build path --> configure build
  path -->under libraries-->add jar-->expand cardview-->expand
  libs-->select android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar

under order and export-->check android.support.v7.widget.CardView.jar-->click

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Yes It helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Please add this line **compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'** in build.gradle file under dependencies.

Please visit this [link](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) for the latest changes has made for any dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved this problem by checking CardView project "Library Module" in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you coming in here looking for Xamarin-specific, once you've added the *Android Support Library v7 CardView* component, you need to **Clean** your project and then re-build.